# app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
import axios from 'axios';
let addToCart = document.querySelectorAll('#add-to-cart');

// post requesta with fetch data
function updateCart(food){
axios.post('/update-cart',food).then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
});
}

addToCart.forEach((btn) =>{
btn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
 let food= JSON.parse(btn.dataset.food);
 updateCart(food)

})
})
```

### when i fix my package.json file by "type": "module" then the eror like "require is not defined"....

Comment: Is this client-side Javascript that runs in the browser?  If so, you can never use `require()` there as that's for nodejs code, not for code that runs in a browser.  Within nodejs code, you use `import` in an ESM module and `require()` in a CommonJS module.  You don't mix the two in the same module.

Comment: yes this is client-side js but now how can i fix this?

Comment: If this is client-side Javascript that is supposed to run in a browser, then why are you running it in nodejs?  I'm thoroughly confused now.  Plus you say the error is `require()` is not defined, but there's no call to `require()` in the code you show.  It's not clear how to help you.

Comment: sir i am biginner in node js...exactly  why this error is occured i dont know...i just find the error try to fix it..thats why i ask here..